# Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, generics, core-data, swiftui

### Background

I have a Core Data Entity `Entry` with a relationship to another Entity `DataField`:

```
class Entry: NSManagedObject {
    //[...]
    @NSManaged public var stringFields: NSSet?
}
```

Because in most cases working with an `NSSet?` isn't practical, `Entry` has another variable:

```
var dataFields: [DataField] {     
    let arr = stringFields?.allObjects as! [DataField]
    return arr.sorted(by: { $0.order < $1.order })
}
```

`DataField` looks like this:

```
class DataField: NSManagedObject {
    //[...]
    @NSManaged var value: String
}
```

And `EntryStore` is my wrapper around the whole thing:

```
class EntryStore: NSObject, BindableObject {
    private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Entry> = {
        //[...]
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }()
    var entries: [Entry] {
        return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ?? []
    }
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<EntryStore, Never>()
    //[...]
}
extension EntryStore: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    public func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        didChange.send(self)
    }
}
```

Finally I pass my `EntryStore` as an `@EnvironmentObject` in the SceneDelegate

### Problem

Though I can use other attributes of `Entity` with a SwiftUI TextField, when I try and use `DataField` I get this error:

> Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred

The code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: EntryStore
    var body: some View {
        TextField($model.entries.first!.dataFields.first!.value)
    }
}
```

I've read that the general form of this error is a result of not explicitly typing variables, but I've tried forcibly casting this expression all sorts of ways to no avail. Also, for what it's worth, the red line in Xcode seems to be on the `.allObjects` part when I moved the `dataFields` conversion inline to the TextField:

```
TextField(($model.stringFields.allObjects.sort(by: { ($0 as! DataField).order < ($1 as! DataField).order }).first!.value)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: In your last example you need a ? after `stringFields` since it's optional. I assume that's why you get a red line

Comment: I had it like that initially but for some reason adding the ? actually produces this error: `Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Binding<NSSet?>`

Comment: Ok, Binding seems to be a new functionality and also something I am not yet familiar with.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `dataFields` didn't notify the `PasstrhoughSubject` when it's value changed - meaning it couldn't be used as a binding.

Here's what I ended up with (also slight changes for beta 4) - first give `Entry` a Publisher:

```
public class Entry: NSManagedObject, BindableObject {
    public let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Entry, Never>()
```

Then use setters and getters to alert the `Combine` framework of changes:

```
var dataFields: [DataField] {
    set {
        willChange.send(self)
    }
    get {
        let arr = stringFields?.allObjects as! [DataField]
        return arr.sorted(by: { $0.order < $1.order })
    }
}

}
```

Now `dataFields` can be used with bindings